# Sending a string with quotation mark in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

How to pass whole string also with quotation marks.

```
#!/bin/bash

my_name="My Value"

function abc(){
    a=$1
    echo $a
}

abc $my_name
```

This gives :

```
My
```

How to get the value as :

```
"My value"
```

also with quotation marks

Comment: The variable doesn't *have* quotation marks; the value of `my_name` is literally `My Value`; the quotes only exist to tell the shell that the space is part of the value, not separating the assignment `my_name=My` from the command `Value`.

Comment: Long discussion at [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing in quotes instead of abc $my_name

> abc "$my_name"

If you want quotes in your output too then try defining as:

`my_name="\"My Value\""`

and then type:

> abc "$my_name"

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to pass your argument within single quotes. This will consider your whole argument as a single string.
Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_name='"My Value"'

function abc(){
    a=$1
    echo "$a"
}

abc "$my_name"
```

Comment: Is it safe on surrounding the sql queries with single quote ' , as need to pass the whole "select .." with quotes